# Encapsulate a multi pass algorithm comprised of operations

Tags: types, f#, functional-programming

I am trying to encapsulate the idea of "multiple passes" of a set of operations.

The idea is that if I run a set of operations, they will produce a new set of operations, those will get run, producing a third set which are then run, and so on. Obviously, there is the danger the algorithm won't terminate, but who cares.

I tried to model it with:

```
type Op = Unit -> Op option

let rec performPass (ops : Op list) : Unit =
    ops |> List.choose (fun x -> x ()) |> performPass
```

The idea was that I could write functions like:

```
let firstPass () =
    // Perform state-changing first-pass
    Some (fun () ->
        // Perform state-changing second-pass
        Some (fun () ->
            // Third pass is the last
            None))
```

But was quickly informed that this is an infinite type. Upon reflection, I agreed that it's infinite but struggled to find another way to represent this.

So, how would you encapsulate a multi pass algorithm where the previous pass generates the code for the next pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The F# compiler does not like *immediate* recursion in *type aliases*, but it will happily let you define a recursive type when you define it as a new type - for example, using single-case discriminated union:

```
type Op = Unit -> Op option             // Type alias does not work
type Op = Op of (Unit -> Op option)     // Single-case union is fine
```

Then you can update your functions as follows:

```
let rec performPass (ops : Op list) : Unit =
    ops |> List.choose (fun (Op x) -> x ()) |> performPass
```

Here, the only change is that I turned `fun x -> x ()` to `fun (Op x) -> x ()` which uses pattern matching on the single case to extract the function from the `Op` type.

```
let firstPass () =
    // Perform state-changing first-pass
    Some (Op (fun () ->
        // Perform state-changing second-pass
        Some (Op (fun () ->
            // Third pass is the last
            None))))
```

Here, I added `Op` in a number of places to wrap the function inside the `Op` type.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try wrapping it in a union! That's perfect... so close...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the general solution, but one fix is to simply limit it to 3 passes:

```
type Op1 = Unit -> Op2
and Op2 = Unit -> Op3
and Op3 = Unit -> Unit

let rec performPasses (ops1 : Op1 list) : Unit =
    let apply x = x ()
    ops1 |> List.map apply |> List.map apply |> List.map apply |> ignore
```